# Wordpress with Owncloud

Tags: 16.04, permissions, wordpress, owncloud-server

and it was working well. Then I installed wordpress and it worked well as well. However, I couldn't access owncloud anymore.

I have owncloud installed at /var/www/owncloud and wordpress installed at /var/www/html. Is it possible to access owncloud working under /var/www/html/owncloud ? so if I access 192.168.1.168:80 I can acccess wordpress and if I access 192.168.1.168:80/owncloud then it would access owncloud ?

I have tried moving owncloud with sudo mv owncloud /var/www/html and I tried accessing owncloud and it said :

```
Data directory (/var/www/owncloud/data) is invalid
Please check that the data directory contains a file ".ocdata" in its root.

Cannot create "data" directory (/var/www/owncloud/data)
This can usually be fixed by giving the webserver write access to the root directory.
```

Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was assisted on IRC for this, when I moved owncloud from /var/www/owncloud to /var/www/html there's a reference in config.php which is  located in owncloud/config/config.php that still had a reference(datadirectory) to the previous path.

When you change this to the updated path this then worked.